# Копирование выделеного текста и отображение его в пункте контекстного меню браузера с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, webbrowser

Разбираюсь в **создании расширения** для браузера Chrome и хочу повторить функционал самого браузера, а именно копирование выделенного текста на любом сайте, в любом месте без привязки к тегам и т.д. и его дальнейшее отображение в пункте контекстного меню браузера(смотрите фото).
[image: Стандартный функционал браузера Chrome]
К моему сожаления не могу такое никак реализовать, недостаточно знаний в этой области, изучаю JS не так давно.

Как создать меню с необходимым пунктом знаю, а вот выделить и скопировать текст никак не получается.

Знающие люди, подскажите, как такое можно реализовать или направьте где и что почитать с этим связано?